# Trying to create a linked list, however my procedure for deleting an item of data is not deleting as it does not output the message when deleted

Tags: vb.net, linked-list

When I fill my linked list with data and try to delete an element, the code does absolutely nothing and I am confused on what is wrong as I checked my code many times. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Public Resp, Counter1, CurrentPointer, NextPointer, StartPointer, Counter, ReturnVal, PrevP As Integer
    Public SearchQ As String
    Structure DP
        Dim Data As String
        Dim Pointer As Integer
    End Structure
    Public LinkedL(10) As DP
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Call Initialise()

        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Select 1 to enter data")
            Console.WriteLine("Select 2 to delete data")
            Console.WriteLine("Select 3 to output data")
            Console.WriteLine("Select -1 to exit")
            Resp = Console.ReadLine
            If Resp = 1 Then
                Call EnterD()
            ElseIf Resp = 2 Then
                Call DeleteD()
            ElseIf Resp = 3 Then
                Call OutputD()
            ElseIf Resp = -1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye")
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub

    Sub Initialise()
        StartPointer = 0
        NextPointer = 0
        Counter1 = 1
        For Counter = 0 To 9
            LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = Counter1
            Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
        Next
        LinkedL(10).Pointer = -1
    End Sub

    Sub EnterD()
        If NextPointer = -1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Linked list is full")
        Else
            CurrentPointer = NextPointer
            Console.WriteLine("Enter data")
            LinkedL(CurrentPointer).Data = Console.ReadLine()
            NextPointer = LinkedL(CurrentPointer).Pointer
            Console.WriteLine("Done")
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteD()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter data to delete")
        SearchQ = Console.ReadLine
        Counter = StartPointer
        ReturnVal = -1
        Do
            If LinkedL(Counter).Data = SearchQ Then
                ReturnVal = LinkedL(Counter).Pointer
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop Until LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = -1
        If LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = -1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Data to be deleted is not found")
        End If
        If ReturnVal <> -1 Then
            Counter = StartPointer
            Do
                If LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = ReturnVal Then
                    PrevP = Counter
                    LinkedL(PrevP).Pointer = LinkedL(ReturnVal).Pointer
                    LinkedL(ReturnVal).Pointer = -1
                End If
            Loop
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully deleted")
        End If


    End Sub

    Sub OutputD()
        Counter = 0
        Do
            Console.WriteLine(LinkedL(Counter).Data)
            Counter = LinkedL(Counter).Pointer
        Loop Until Counter = -1

    End Sub

End Module
```

I have a slight doubt that my code used to search for the pointer needed to be deleted has an issue, as the message saying "Deleted." is not being output. I'm expecting my delete procedure to delete the code however it is not doing so as I am not getting the message.

Comment: Any particular reason for representing your "linked list" with a structure and a "pointer" that is really just an integer that points to a spot in the array? You really should use a `Class`, instead of a structure, and make the "Pointer" actually reference another instance of your class: `Public Class DP
        Dim Data As String
        Dim Pointer As DP
    End Class`

Comment: @Borkode I see from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725162/when-trying-to-delete-an-element-in-a-linked-list-it-deletes-the-element-right) that you used my answer in your code. Please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are not incrementing `Counter` and the loop is stuck with `StartPointer`. You should add `Counter += 1` in your loop:

```
If ReturnVal <> -1 Then
    Counter = StartPointer
    Do
        If LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = ReturnVal Then
            PrevP = Counter
            LinkedL(PrevP).Pointer = LinkedL(ReturnVal).Pointer
            LinkedL(ReturnVal).Pointer = -1
        End If
        Counter += 1
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully deleted")
End If
```