# When trying to delete an element in a linked list, it deletes the element right after it

Tags: vb.net, linked-list

For example if I input into the linked list the following, each quote is 1 element.

"Hello"
"This"
"Is"
"Not"
"A"
"Test"

and then I tell it to delete the element containing "Not", it will delete "A"

Here is my code:

```
Module Program
    Public Resp, Counter1, CurrentPointer, NextPointer, StartPointer, Counter, ReturnVal, PrevP As Integer
    Public SearchQ As String
    Structure DP
        Dim Data As String
        Dim Pointer As Integer
    End Structure
    Public LinkedL(10) As DP
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Call Initialise()

        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Select 1 to enter data")
            Console.WriteLine("Select 2 to delete data")
            Console.WriteLine("Select 3 to output data")
            Console.WriteLine("Select -1 to exit")
            Resp = Console.ReadLine
            If Resp = 1 Then
                Call EnterD()
            ElseIf Resp = 2 Then
                Call DeleteD()
            ElseIf Resp = 3 Then
                Call OutputD()
            ElseIf Resp = -1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye")
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub

    Sub Initialise()
        StartPointer = 0
        NextPointer = 0
        Counter1 = 1
        For Counter = 0 To 9
            LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = Counter1
            Counter1 += 1
        Next
        LinkedL(10).Pointer = -1
    End Sub

    Sub EnterD()
        If NextPointer = -1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Linked list is full")
        Else
            CurrentPointer = NextPointer
            Console.WriteLine("Enter data")
            LinkedL(CurrentPointer).Data = Console.ReadLine()
            NextPointer = LinkedL(CurrentPointer).Pointer
            Console.WriteLine("Done")
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteD()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter data to delete")
        SearchQ = Console.ReadLine
        Counter = StartPointer
        ReturnVal = -1
        Do
            If LinkedL(Counter).Data = SearchQ Then
                ReturnVal = LinkedL(Counter).Pointer
                Exit Do
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Loop Until LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = -1
        If LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = -1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Data to be deleted is not found")
        End If
        If ReturnVal <> -1 Then
            Counter = 0
            Do
                If LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = ReturnVal Then
                    PrevP = Counter
                    LinkedL(PrevP).Pointer = LinkedL(ReturnVal).Pointer
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Counter += 1
                End If
            Loop
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully deleted")
        End If


    End Sub

    Sub OutputD()
        Counter = StartPointer
        Do
            Console.WriteLine(LinkedL(Counter).Data)
            Counter = LinkedL(Counter).Pointer
        Loop Until Counter = -1

    End Sub

End Module
```

It is supposed to delete "Not" however it deletes "A" instead. I think this is a logic issue however I can't crack what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're mixing up the pointer and the counter. Your zeroith element has a pointer of 1, and so it goes wrong from there. Either start Counter1 at 0, or subtrack when you think you've "found" the element you want.

Comment: But the thing is, the pointer of the 0th element is supposed to be 1 because it is pointing to the next element, that's why the 1st element points to 2 and so on.

Comment: What's happening here when you debug: `LinkedL(PrevP).Pointer = LinkedL(ReturnVal).Pointer` Is the correct element getting the correct new pointer value?

Comment: Here is a link that explains linked list OPS, https://teachics.org/data-structure-c-tutorial/linked-list-operations-with-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

In your DeleteD method you need to be updating the previous element:

```
        If ReturnVal <> -1 Then
            Counter = 0
            Do
                If LinkedL(Counter).Pointer = ReturnVal Then
                    PrevP = Counter - 1
                    LinkedL(PrevP).Pointer = LinkedL(ReturnVal - 1).Pointer
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Counter += 1
                End If
            Loop
        End If
```